# How to convert utc datetime between any time zones using the Windows API?

Tags: windows, datetime, timezone

We are looking for ways to convert utc datetimes between timezones (in both directions) using Windows API, ie. using the Windows timezone data, maintained by Microsoft.

Is this possible?

The SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTimeEx and TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTimeEx seem to fit the bill, however both need a correct DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, which moves the goalpost to obtaining a correct DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION structure.

GetTimeZoneInformation and GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation only provide the current timezone.

GetTimeZoneInformationForYear (which will be required for converting past datetimes) requires a dynamic timezone as input.

How can you get valid timezone information structure for another timezone?

The information is in the registry, but as a TZI field binary, is there a spec on how that TZI field is decodable into TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION ?

There is a EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation from Win2012 up, but we cannot rely on it since we need to support Win2008R2...

***PS:*** using TZDB for our needs is problematic as we would be responsible for updating it in the field. A key aspect of this question is that we want a way to convert between TZ without having to maintain and deploy the TZ information ourselves, given that [can change very quickly](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+KristianK%C3%B6hntopp/posts/KdnGy145ju8).

Comment: WRT your PS, You do realize that the Windows update for that particular scenario lagged 6 weeks behind the TZDB update, right?  [See my blog on this topic](http://codeofmatt.com/2016/07/01/time-zone-chaos-inevitable-in-egypt/).  IMHO, you're always better retaining control of your own TZ updates.

Comment: @Matt, yes, I do, but if the TZDB is maintained by MS, then blame and burden falls on MS (and Egypt). If it is maintained by us, blame and burden falls on us (and IT guys at the customers). And it is not like we would be able to monetize that extra burden, so maintaining the TZDB ourselves puts us in the proverbial lose-lose situation...

Comment: I hear you.  Though IMHO, you're better off being able to update when you need to then to be waiting on others.  I suppose it depends on how critical TZ updates are for the particular application.  Also, it is indeed possible to write code to self-update the local TZDB data with each IANA release.  I've not done that in C++, but I've done it in C# with Noda Time, and I know at least one person who's done it in Elixr.

Comment: Actually, it looks like [Howard Hinnant's Date Library for C++](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) has an `AUTO_DOWNLOAD` feature.  I've not tried it myself, but it appears to keep up to date with TZDB releases from IANA.  [More here](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html).  Not sure if it is updated only at compile time or at runtime also.

Comment: We are deployed at hundreds of industrial sites, usually on machines that do not have internet accesses (or are firewalled heavily), auto-updates are just not possible. Merely notifying every admins about the need to update would already be a complicated process between off-site admins, contractors, corporate update policies, vetting processes, plus the risks in case a tzdb update proves bugged... And as said, no way for all of this to pay for itself, so this is a pure risk and burden we have no incentive to shoulder...

Comment: That's too bad.  In general, when time zone data can't be reliably updated, there are problems [like these](http://codeofmatt.com/2016/04/23/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/).  I think you'll find the same issue with Windows data - if updates can't regularly be installed, you may eventually calculate time zone conversions inaccurately - especially if a government changes their rules with short notice.  At minimum, make sure these machines can receive updates via Windows Update or WSUS.  If possible, avoid doing the conversions at all if your app doesn't really need it.  Good luck to you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Enumerating the registry seems to be the only way, the TZI field structure is described at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481(v=vs.85).aspx and is as follows

```
typedef struct _REG_TZI_FORMAT
{
    LONG Bias;
    LONG StandardBias;
    LONG DaylightBias;
    SYSTEMTIME StandardDate;
    SYSTEMTIME DaylightDate;
} REG_TZI_FORMAT;
```

Comment: Since you cannot use `EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation` due to needing to support Win2008R2, I agree that you will need to populate the entries from the registry yourself.